# Merging two tables including the union on all values in a single column in Athena (Presto)

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

Here is table 1:

```
prof_id title id date0
1       Z     0  4/3
1       A     0  4/3
1       B     0  4/4
1       C     0  4/4
2       C     0  4/6
2       D     0  4/6
2       E     0  4/6
```

Here is table 2:

```
 title id date1
  A     0 1/2
  C     0 1/2
  D     0 1/3
  E     0 1/3
  H     0 1/5
  J     0 1/6
```

I'd like to create a table like this:

```
prof_id date0  title id date1
1       4/3    Z     0  NA
1       4/3    A     0  1/2
1       4/3    B     0  NA
1       4/4    C     0  1/2
2       4/4    C     0  1/2
2       4/6    D     0  1/3
2       4/6    E     0  1/3
NA      NA     H     0  1/5
NA      NA     J     0  1/6
```

The column in the title in this case would be title. I'm pretty new to SQL so any help would be much appreciated.

Note: I'm running this on Amazon Athena

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.)?  "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.

Comment: Sorry about that, i'm running my queries on AWS Athena

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using a full outer join:

```
SELECT
    t1.prof_id,
    t1.date0,
    COALESCE(t1.title, t2.title) AS title,
    COALESCE(t1.id, t2.id) AS id,
    t2.date1
FROM table1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.title = t2.title AND
       t1.id = t2.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. This is ANSI so should work on any of the major DBMS:

```
SELECT a.prof_id, a.date0, b.title, b.id, b.datet1
FROM [table 1] a 
RIGHT JOIN [table 2] b ON a.title = b.title
```